# Spreading/smoothing periodic tasks out over time

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, statistics, probability

I have a database table with `N` records, each of which needs to be refreshed every 4 hours.  The "refresh" operation is pretty resource-intensive.  I'd like to write a scheduled task that runs occasionally and refreshes them, while smoothing out the spikes of load.

The simplest task I started with is this (pseudocode):

```
every 10 minutes:
    find all records that haven't been refreshed in 4 hours
    for each record:
        refresh it
        set its last refresh time to now
```

(Technical detail: "refresh it" above is asynchronous; it just queues a task for a worker thread pool to pick up and execute.)

What this causes is a huge resource (CPU/IO) usage spike every 4 hours, with the machine idling the rest of the time.  Since the machine also does other stuff, this is bad.

I'm trying to figure out a way to get these refreshes to be more or less evenly spaced out -- that is, I'd want around `N/(10mins/4hours)`, that is `N/24`, of those records, to be refreshed on every run.  Of course, it doesn't need to be exact.

Notes:

- I'm fine with the algorithm taking time to start working (so say, for the first 24 hours there will be spikes but those will smooth out over time), as I only rarely expect to take the scheduler offline.
- Records are constantly being added and removed by other threads, so so we can't assume anything about the value of `N` between iterations.
- I'm fine with records being refreshed every 4 hours +/- 20 minutes.

Comment: Is it a problem if a record is updated more frequently, like twice in 10 minutes? Not in the long term, of course, but it might simplify things if this was allowed during the initial transition.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine.  It's clear that evening things out will cause more work to be done overall, but I'm okay with that so long as (in the average case) the CPU doesn't get thrashed.

Comment: How long does the update usually take? (i.e. how long until the job queue is empty?)

Comment: With my current configuration (30 worker threads running refreshes, around 1,000 records), each full refresh overloads the machine for 5-7 minutes before it empties the queue.

Comment: Couldn't you just grab the oldest `N/24` records every 10 minutes? If you do a full refresh 10 minutes before the first run, the refresh intervals should stabilise after one 4-hour cycle, and the workload would be steady from the get-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a full refresh, to get all your timestamps in sync. From that point on, every 10 minutes, refresh the oldest N/24 records.

The load will be steady from the start, and after 24 runs (4 hours), all your records will be updating at 4-hour intervals (if N is fixed). Insertions will decrease refresh intervals; deletions may cause increases or decreases, depending on the deleted record's timestamp. But I suspect you'd need to be deleting quite a lot (like, 10% of your table at a time) before you start pushing anything outside your 40-minute window. To be on the safe side, you could do a few more than N/24 each run.

Comment: Great solution, especially because it's so simple.  I added a forced refresh of any records that are older than 4:20 so that no records are left stale too long, even in the face of deletions or missed schedules for the task.

Answer (score 0):

```
Each minute: 
  take all records older than 4:10 , refresh them
  If the previous step did not find a lot of records:
      Take some of the oldest records older than 3:40, refresh them.
```

This should eventually make the last update time more evenly spaced out. What "a lot" and "some" means You should decide Yourself (possibly based on N).

Answer (score 0):

Give each record its own refreshing interval time, which is a random number between 3:40 and 4:20.